Error during the deployment of my Maven project
please, when I try to deploy my Maven application with Tomcat, it generates this error. What could be the problem, please?
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  0.486 s
Finished at: 2024-07-31T10:14:22+01:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project BeinxInv: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.beinxinv:BeinxInv:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk18:jar:5.0.5 (absent): org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk18:jar:5.0.5 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I want you to help me solve this problem.

Could you please try as below?: (As you will be using Java 8)
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaybird</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.java8</version>
</dependency>

As i see in Maven central repository with "jaybird-jdk18" artifact id, last version seems to be 4.0.10.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.10.java8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

